# Set height of the categories meta box in post dashboard

Tags: metabox

How can I set height of the categories checkbox meta box? The one thats shows when we want to post a new article.
I have found this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-the-fixed-heigth-of-the-box-filled-with-checkboxes-named-category but it is not working.

When I try to debug in Chrome I can disable max-height, it works great, but when I go in css and put the same copypasted code with changed values it just won't.

```
.categorydiv div.tabs-panel, .customlinkdiv div.tabs-panel, .posttypediv div.tabs-panel, .taxonomydiv div.tabs-panel, .wp-tab-panel {
min-height: 42px;
max-height: 500px; // 200px is default
overflow: auto;
}
```

I just want to have larger box, because I have a lot of categories and scrolling is a bit tiresome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am correct the `style.css` (your theme `style.css`) is not loaded in the admin area so creating a function solves this.

> Side note: The code you where looking for I found in `wp-admin/css/edit.css` at line 960

Below you find the function,hopefully this is what you where looking for.
*Make backup from `functions.php` (you know the drill)*

Add following function to `functions.php`

```
function change_cat_meta_postbox_css(){
   ?>
   <style type="text/css">
   .wp-tab-panel, .categorydiv div.tabs-panel,
   .customlinkdiv div.tabs-panel,
   .posttypediv div.tabs-panel,
   .taxonomydiv div.tabs-panel {
       min-height: 42px;
       max-height: 500px;/* change this to own wishes */
       overflow: auto;
       padding: 0 0.9em;
       border: solid 1px #dfdfdf;
       background-color: #fdfdfd;
   }
   </style><?php
}
add_action('admin_head', 'change_cat_meta_postbox_css');
```

Take a look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes) for some more info.

> Just as a reminder, to change layout in the admin area(back-end) you need to create a `function` and the correct [`hook`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) to achieve your goal.

*side note 2:* It probably changes height for all meta postboxes but find the right div and add it to the function should also solve that, cheers.